# Pass node Array to JavaScript in ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I want to pass the Array from my app.js into JavaScript from my EJS File. In my loop function I want to fill some data into objects to push them into a JS Array for an appointment Calendar. But I can't pass the data..
Here's my Code Snippet:

app.js:

```
router.route ('/torauswahl').get(function (req, res) {

    Buchung.find(function (err, buchungen) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);

        res.render('torauswahl',{
            buchungen: JSON.stringify(buchungen)
        });
    });
});
```

And the JS in my EJS:

```
var appointments = [];
        var appointment = {};
        var buchungArray = <%=buchungen %>;

        for(var i=0; i < buchungArray.length; i++) {
            var monat = 1 + buchungArray[i].from.getMonth();
            var von = -1 + buchungArray[i].from.getHours();
            var vonMin = buchungArray[i].from.getMinutes();
            var bisMonat = 1 + buchungArray[i].from.getMonth();
            var bis = -1 + buchungArray[i].to.getHours();
            var bisMin = buchungArray[i].to.getMinutes();

            if (bisMin === 0) {
                bisMin = bisMin + "0";
            }
            if (vonMin === 0) {
                vonMin = vonMin + "0";
            }

            appointment[i] = {
                calendar: buchungArray[i].tor,
                start: new Date(buchungArray[i].from.getDate(), monat, buchungArray[i].from.getDay(), von, vonMin, 0),
                end: new Date(buchungArray[i].to.getDate(), bisMonat, buchungArray[i].to.getDay(), bis, bisMin, 0)
            }
            appointments.push(appointment[i]);
        }
```

Where i declare the buchungArray, IntelliJ shows me an Error with : Expression expected.
Im thankful for any help!
Cheeres, Mert

Comment: What does the **rendered** client-side JS look like?

Comment: "Where i declare the buchungArray, IntelliJ shows me an Error" — Well, presumably it is trying to treat your EJS template as JavaScript … which it isn't. Does the code work when it is rendered and sent to the browser?

Comment: Thats the second code section above.

Comment: No. The second code section shows the EJS template, not the JavaScript you get when you render it.

Comment: @Quentin I don't know.. I'm new in learning EJS and have to excecute JavaScript with the rendered variable I passed in my app.js

Comment: "I don't know" — So open it in a browser and View > Source.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question my fault :D So the buchungsArray is getting filled with the data I have in my DB

Comment: Node.js takes the EJS file and the object you pass to `render`, combines them, then sends the result to the browser. What does that result look like? (And I mean what does it **really** look like. Not what is it supposed to look like. Not what you think it looks like. Make a request to `/torauswahl` and then look at the source in the browser).

Comment: @Quentin the result is not displayed in my browser but in the Source the buchungsArray isn't formatted well. in Strings for example its like: **user: &#39;GLS&#39;,** But user is just GLS.

Answer (score 2):

`<%=buchungen %>` escapes data for inserting into HTML but you are inserting it into a `<script>` where normal HTML rules for escaping don't apply.

You can get the raw output with `<%- buchungen %>`.

Your IDE is still likely to complain as it tries to process your EJS template as if it were pure JavaScript. You might want to store the data somewhere else such as in a `data` attribute.

```
<script data-buchungen="<%=buchungen %>">
    var buchungArray = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.dataset.buchungen);
    // etc
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I have still the problem, that strings are not formatted like I said in the comment above. do you know why?

Comment: For the same reason, but it doesn't matter because normal HTML escaping rules *do* apply in the attribute value, so the browser will have decoded them by the time it passes `document.currentScript.dataset.buchungen` to the JS.

Comment: Okay perfect, thank you! But I think there's something wrong in my loop function, because I can't see the appointment objects.. do you know why?

Comment: I get an error in my browser: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.currentScript.dataset') is it normal?

Comment: @MertSilva — No. https://jsbin.com/lacalezivi/edit?html,console works fine for me.